# sbt package error: Couldn't retrieve source module: org.scala-sbt:compiler-interface:0.13.16:component

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, sbt

My sbt_version is 0.13.16. Is this problem caused by the version mismatch? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Niki. You can edit your question to add more detail about your question. Do not add your detail in the answer.  Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once

Answer (score 0):

Your scala plugin is probably broken. You can remove the scala plugin and install it again. Or you can manually download the latest plugin and use it in you IDE.